# Send ONLY $_POST variables to PHP using AJAX, without HTML response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

I'm trying to send only `$_POST`'s variables (vars from the `$_POST` array) into PHP file using AJAX call. I don't want to say on success: `alert('ok, it's fine')` or `$('blah').text('done it!')`. I'd like to post variables into `$_POST` table of the PHP file and nothing more. Ok, let's look into my files below:

`ajax.php`

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/media/system/js/jquery_check.js"></script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/ajax.js"></script>';
```

`ajax.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id:12345,whatever:'blahblah' },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
    });
});
```

So, when I run `ajax.php` with this example, I get alert info:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost.dev/media/system/js/jquery_check.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost.dev/ajax.js"></script>
```

If I put e.g. `jQuery('#photoid').text(data);` in the success function and add `<div id="photoid"></div>` in the PHP file, and additionally `var_dump($_POST)`, I'll get this HTML response on the screen (and as an alert info as well):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost.dev/media/system/js/jquery_check.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost.dev/ajax.js"></script>array(2) { ["id"]=> string(5) "12345" ["whatever"]=> string(8) "blahblah" } <div id="photoid"></div>
```

What I want to make is a call that will make my PHP file have only post data stuff sent (`id` and `whatever`) and written into `$_POST` superglobal array in the PHP file. So I don't need these script stuff etc. because in my real PHP script I don't need to have any HTML data displayed on the site, only POST data received by PHP file. Is that possible?

Anyway the `div` code is needless for me, but as I see it's needed to exist in order to have possibility to read any POST data. Also the POST data are being written into `array(1)` or `array(2)` instead of the standard `$_POST` array so I can only read data by using `foreach` loop (`$_POST['id']` shows error with no such index available).

I'm using XAMPP locally if it's important. But this should work locally too.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't want to do anything, then don't define `success` callback. What is the problem?

Comment: Yep, chanchal118, that would be a great solution, but I need to use these $_POST vars in my PHP file, but I can't. They're not available, just var_dump($_POST) says: {0}.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the

```
success: function (data) {
    alert(data);
}
```

part from your script. for documentation check [Jquery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Ok, but now my var_dump($_POST) array is null and if I wanted to show e.g. echo $_POST['id'] - a notice shows: "Notice: Undefined index: id in X:\ajax.php on line 7" - no data is shown by PHP. Firebug shows response data, but var_dump says it's not available.. how can I use it now? PS.I've read a bit of jQuery documentation and read a lot of stackoverflow (+ uncle Google) questions with no effect. So I tried a lot of different kind of codes. This is just example, but says everything about what I need to make it complete and working.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`$.getScript()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/), which is specifically for this. Since you wanna fire a `POST` request, you can use `$.ajax()` this way.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      dataType: "script",
    });
});
```

Comment: Praveen Kumar, generally let's say `ajax.php` file has `ajax.js` loaded already (in my real php script). Because the JS script has a lot of functions inside and I want to use just three of them (running only once by chaining, but not directly in the JS file - I want it being run from the PHP file by executing e.g. <script>myfunction()</script>). So here in the example I've showed, this would be identical. But has no effect at al. Var_dump($_POST) still shows {0}.